# Show a message after login in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a login function in angularjs :

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('/users/login', $scope.user).then(function(result) {
        if (result.data.userid) {
            $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
            $cookies.put('userid', result.data.userid);
            $rootScope.userid = result.data.userid;
            $scope.message = result.data.msg;
            //$window.location = '/';
        } else {
            $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
            $scope.message = result.data.msg;
        }
    });
  }
```

after login, I want to show userid through $rootScope.userid to the html and flash a message $scope.message. If i want to show userid, I have to reload the page by `$window.location = '/'` because it doen not change automically. But if I reload the page, I cannot flash the message. Can anyone suggest me a solution for it ? Thank you

Comment: how are you trying to show userId in html? could you paste that code as well?

Comment: <h2 ng-hide = "!userid" >{{userid}}</h2>
like this

Comment: Looks good, just for testing try $root.userid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such scenario, I would use ui-router and have arranged routes and controllers scopes as below:

- appController (this is parent state to all other states)

  - loginController (child state)
  - indexController (child state)
  - anyOtherControllers (child state)

In Login controller

1. after successful login, I would raise an event using $emil. this event will be handled in appController using $on. the appController then shows the login message.
2. login controller would change route to desired view using $state.go() e.g. $state.go('index').

Hope this helps.